# rails turbolinks onerror javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image, turbolinks

I want to hide an image when the link of the image is broken (404 not found).
When i trigger an `onerror:hideImage(this)` on my image it works once and then because of Turbolinks, it hides all the images after a refresh.
Is there a solution?

```
function hideImage(source){
    source.hide();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ok, found the solution:

add `onerror:"this.style.display='none'"` to your image_tag and it's done!